Will this work to ground a cheap soldering iron?
I have a cheap 220V AC soldering iron with no ground. I am in UK where mains plugs have three pin and  where the middle pin is the ground pin.   Hence for soldering with sensitive components it may damage them because of ESD discharge. So for soldering ESD sensitive components can I do the following.

Heat up the soldering to required temperature.
Plug out the soldering iron.
Using a pre wired a mains plug with with a single wire to the earth wire coming out of the plug. Briefly touch the tip of the soldering iron to the above earth wire coming out of the plug to discharge and earth the soldering iron
While it is cooling do some soldering while the soldering iron is hot enough.

Would this work?

why would step #2 be necessary?

@jsotola to stop putting in more electrons into the soldering iron-I am just  making and educated guess in my question.

The UK single phase has neutral, line,, and earth. The neutral is either tied to earth at the panel or at the substation. I think you may be over thinking this. Check to see if the tip ohm's out to the neutral.

Are you better off with a tip that is truly grounded, which would short-circuit the mains if it touched a live wire, and which could cause ESD from a charged device (e.g., through static electricity), or with the tip isolated (which you'd need to check), but connected to ground through a 250 kΩ or larger resistor? That is the normal procedure for personnel ESD prevention. (you might use two resistors in series, lest one short.

@Z.E. to stop putting in more electrons into the soldering iron ... the tip is not electrically connected to the heating element... you would get electrocuted if it was connected

@periblepsis Check to see if the tip ohm's out to the neutral. If it does "ohm out" to neutral, the iron should be immediately discarded. The tip should never be connected to mains, neutral or not! It can be connected to "ground" (PE) - should be, in fact, in a 240V-powered iron without transformer isolation.
